# Convert Map to POJO while maintaining original Types in Java

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I need to convert a Map<String, Object> into a POJO and maintain all original types of the Map.

Take as example this simple POJO:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class mObj{
    private String id;
    private Object value;
}
```

I need value to be of same type store inside Map<String, Object>.
So if my map is:

```
Map<String, Object> data = Map.of("id", "123",  "value", OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")));
```

then I'm expecting after converting to myObj that class of Object value is OffsetDateTime.

I've tried to use Jackson for the conversion and though it seems to retain most types, it's not working fine for timestamp classes like java.time.OffsetDateTime. Instead it converts it to String.

How can I maintain the original type coming in the Map for this kind of cases?

Comment: Why are you roundtripping through Jackson? Why are you not directly creating instances of `mObj`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine with using the setters you acquire from Lombok:

```java
var mObjList = data.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            mObj myMObj = new mObj();
            myMObj.setId(entry.getKey());
            myMObj.setValue(entry.getValue());
            return myMObj;
        }).toList();
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend adding an @AllArgsConstructor to your class to allow this simplification:

```java
var mObjList = data.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new mObj(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .toList();
```

Comment: Actually I was looking in a more generic way to do this instead of directly create mObj like suggested cause I want to extend this to be able to convert a given Map to any given Pojo